# Create Passenger Name Record - Message NO FARE FOR CLASS USED

Tags: sabre

We are using Bargain Finder Max and Create Passenger Name Record to book flights

We are seeing an issue with approx 50% of our test cases where we see the following error returned from the Create PNR call

```
"code":"ERR.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR","content":"Unable to perform air booking step"
```

Followed by

```
[{"Message":[{"code":"WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE", "content":"EnhancedAirBookRQ: NO FARE FOR CLASS USED"}]
```

Our Create PNR call is using the responses from a BFM call

As you can see,  we are passing ResBookDesigCode of B and W,  which we retrieve from the BFM call

Here is the truncated detail we want to book from the BFM call,  it's 4 flight return,  and we are using a priced pair of itineraries,  we aren't trying to use an out from one priced Itin and return from another.

```
...[{
"DepartureDateTime": "2018-12-23T06:00:00",
"ArrivalDateTime": "2018-12-23T08:40:00",
"StopQuantity": 0,
"FlightNumber": "345",
"ResBookDesigCode": "B",
"ElapsedTime": 100,
"DepartureAirport": {
    "LocationCode": "LHR",
    "TerminalID": "2",
    "content": ""
},
"ArrivalAirport": {
    "LocationCode": "ZRH",
    "content": ""
},
"OperatingAirline": {
    "Code": "LX",
    "FlightNumber": "345",
    "content": ""
},
"Equipment": [{
    "AirEquipType": "320",
    "content": ""
}],
"MarketingAirline": {
    "Code": "LX",
    "content": ""
},
"MarriageGrp": "O",
"DepartureTimeZone": {
    "GMTOffset": 0.0
},
"ArrivalTimeZone": {
    "GMTOffset": 1.0
},
"TPA_Extensions": {
    "eTicket": {
        "Ind": true
    },
    "Mileage": {
        "Amount": 491
    }
}
```

}...

Here is our Create PNR Call

```
{
"CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
    "version": "2.1.0",
    "targetCity": "XXXX",
    "haltOnAirPriceError": true,
    "TravelItineraryAddInfo": {
        "AgencyInfo": {
            "Address": {
                "AddressLine": "XXXXXX",
                "CityName": "XXXXX",
                "CountryCode": "GB",
                "PostalCode": "XXX XXX",
                "StateCountyProv": {
                    "StateCode": "XXXXX"
                },
                "StreetNmbr": "XXXXX"
            },
            "Ticketing": {
                "TicketType": "XXXX"
            }
        },
        "CustomerInfo": {
            "ContactNumbers": {
                "ContactNumber": [{
                    "NameNumber": "1.1",
                    "Phone": "0844 555 5555 ",
                    "PhoneUseType": "B"
                }]
            },
            "CreditCardData": {
                "BillingInformation": {
                    "cardHolderName": "XXXXX",
                    "streetAddress": "XXXX",
                    "city": "Feering",
                    "stateOrProvince": "Essex",
                    "PostalCode": "XXXXX"
                }
            },
            "PersonName": [{
                "NameNumber": "",
                "NameReference": "",
                "PassengerType": "ADT",
                "GivenName": "BOB",
                "Surname": "BOBBINGTON"
            }]
        }
    },
    "AirBook": {
        "HaltOnStatus": [{
            "Code": "NN"
        }, {
            "Code": "HL"
        }, {
            "Code": "KK"
        }, {
            "Code": "LL"
        }, {
            "Code": "NO"
        }, {
            "Code": "UC"
        }, {
            "Code": "US"
        }],
        "OriginDestinationInformation": {
            "FlightSegment": [{
                "DepartureDateTime": "2018-12-23T06:00:00",
                "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-12-23T08:40:00",
                "FlightNumber": "345",
                "NumberInParty": "1",
                "ResBookDesigCode": "B",
                "Status": "NN",
                "InstantPurchase": true,
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "ZRH"
                },
                "MarketingAirline": {
                    "Code": "LX",
                    "FlightNumber": "345"
                },
                "MarriageGrp": "O",
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "LHR"
                }
            }, {
                "DepartureDateTime": "2018-12-23T11:45:00",
                "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-12-23T14:25:00",
                "FlightNumber": "2114",
                "NumberInParty": "1",
                "ResBookDesigCode": "B",
                "Status": "NN",
                "InstantPurchase": true,
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "AGP"
                },
                "MarketingAirline": {
                    "Code": "LX",
                    "FlightNumber": "2114"
                },
                "MarriageGrp": "O",
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "ZRH"
                }
            }, {
                "DepartureDateTime": "2018-12-24T13:00:00",
                "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-12-24T15:40:00",
                "FlightNumber": "2111",
                "NumberInParty": "1",
                "ResBookDesigCode": "W",
                "Status": "NN",
                "InstantPurchase": true,
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "ZRH"
                },
                "MarketingAirline": {
                    "Code": "LX",
                    "FlightNumber": "2111"
                },
                "MarriageGrp": "O",
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "AGP"
                }
            }, {
                "DepartureDateTime": "2018-12-24T20:55:00",
                "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-12-24T21:40:00",
                "FlightNumber": "340",
                "NumberInParty": "1",
                "ResBookDesigCode": "W",
                "Status": "NN",
                "InstantPurchase": true,
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "LHR"
                },
                "MarketingAirline": {
                    "Code": "LX",
                    "FlightNumber": "340"
                },
                "MarriageGrp": "O",
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "ZRH"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "AirPrice": [{
        "PriceComparison": {
            "AmountSpecified": 403,
            "AcceptablePriceIncrease": {
                "HaltOnNonAcceptablePrice": true,
                "Amount": 847
            }
        },
        "PriceRequestInformation": {
            "Retain": true,
            "OptionalQualifiers": {
                "FOP_Qualifiers": {
                    "BasicFOP": {
                        "Type": "CK"
                    }
                },
                "PricingQualifiers": {
                    "NameSelect": [{
                        "NameNumber": "1.1"
                    }],
                    "PassengerType": [{
                        "Code": "ADT",
                        "Quantity": "1"
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }],
    "MiscSegment": {
        "VendorPrefs": {
            "Airline": {
                "Code": "LX"
            }
        },
        "DepartureDateTime": "12-23",
        "NumberInParty": 1,
        "Text": "TEST OTH MISCELLANEOUS SEGMENT",
        "Type": "OTH",
        "OriginLocation": {
            "LocationCode": "LHR"
        },
        "Status": "GK"
    },
    "SpecialReqDetails": {
        "AddRemark": {
            "RemarkInfo": {
                "FOP_Remark": {
                    "Type": "CASH"
                }
            }
        },
        "SpecialService": {
            "SpecialServiceInfo": {
                "SecureFlight": [{
                    "SegmentNumber": "A",
                    "PersonName": {
                        "DateOfBirth": "1977-07-17",
                        "Gender": "M",
                        "NameNumber": "1.1",
                        "GivenName": "BOB",
                        "Surname": "BOBBINGTON"
                    },
                    "VendorPrefs": {
                        "Airline": {
                            "Hosted": false
                        }
                    }
                }],
                "Service": []
            }
        }
    },
    "PostProcessing": {
        "RedisplayReservation": true,
        "ARUNK": "please do the arunk thing",
        "EndTransaction": {
            "Source": {
                "ReceivedFrom": "SP TEST"
            }
        },
        "PostBookingHKValidation": {
            "waitInterval": 100,
            "numAttempts": 6
        },
        "WaitForAirlineRecLoc": {
            "waitInterval": 100,
            "numAttempts": 6
        }
    }
}
```

}

I've been reading SO posts that state "That's how it is,  prices change",  but if that was the case why when we start the process again, we are offered the same pricing and availability on subsequent calls?

Comment: Why do you have the misc segment in there? And have you tried without?

Comment: Traced this to what appears to be a misreported error,  the issue was related to some airlines taking longer to confirm bookings than others.   we needed to call a Redisplay to continue to requery the p[rocess,  set this redisplay to 9 times max with 2 second delay and we are now seeing sucessful bookings